# Prove various Delta function identities

Tags: dirac-delta

In this [link](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwiYqJ_Irqz2AhUOS_EDHSp0CaUQFnoECBkQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.reed.edu%2Fphysics%2Ffaculty%2Fwheeler%2Fdocuments%2FMiscellaneous%2520Math%2FDelta%2520Functions%2FSimplified%2520Dirac%2520Delta.pdf&usg=AOvVaw1ZnD2Wk6FoJo8vV71npJXB) I found an interesting document about the properties of the Dirac delta function.

Then I checked for three identities that puzzled me:

\begin{equation}
\begin{array}
f\delta(t)e^t=\delta(t) \\
\delta(t)\cos t=\delta(t) \\
\delta(t)\sin t=0
\end{array}
\end{equation}

How can I prove this?

I tried using integration

\begin{equation}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty\delta(t)e^tdt=\delta(t)e^t-\int_{-\infty}^\infty \delta(t)'e^tdt
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty \delta(t)'e^tdt=\delta(t)'e^t-\int_{-\infty}^\infty \delta(t)''e^tdt
\end{equation}

But this seems to no avail.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Your title and question body do not match. I suspect all these identities come from the fact that $\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x) \delta(x) dx = f(0)$, so that in all meaningful places $f(x)\delta(x)$ can be replaced by $f(0) \delta(x)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to perform all calculations in the sense of distributions, i.e., take a test function $\psi$ and "integrate" against it. $\delta(t) e^t = \delta(t)$ is not a pointwise equality. It's an equality between two distributions. Two distributions $f, g$ are said to be equal if: $\int f(t) \psi(t)\ dt =  \int g(t) \psi(t) \ dt $ for any test function $\psi$.

By definition: $\int \delta(t) \psi(t) \ dt = \psi(0)$. Thus:
$$
\int \delta(t) e^t \psi(t) \ dt =  e^0 \psi(0) = \psi(0) = \int \delta(t)  \psi(t) \ dt
$$
Thus, $\delta(t) e^t = \delta(t)$ in the sense of distributions. Same logic applies to the remaining identities.